# Should I just create a Category Schema instead?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, chakra-ui

I want to create a Drawer Component that lists a Main Category and a Sub Category underneath it. When a user clicks on the sub category link, I want to render a component (Accordian.jsx) that shows a list of products related to that sub category.

What I also want to occur is when a user adds a product and chooses the main and sub category for that product, I want the Drawer component to update with a new main and sub category for the first time when a new product is created there.

I've looked at other questions related to creating a main and sub category in StackOverFlow, but they don't fit my circumstance.

I have my category field in my Product Schema defined as this :

```
category: {
    mainCategory: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      },
      subCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
  },
```

Here are my two controller functions :

```
import Product from "../models/Product.js";


export const getProductByCategory = async (req,res) => {
    try {
    const { mainCategory, subCategory } = req.params;
    const products = await Product.find({
      'category.mainCategory': mainCategory,
      'category.subCategory': subCategory
    }).select('image title price description location condition category seller');
    res.status(200).json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
};

export const getMainCategories = async (req,res) => {
    const mainCategory = req.params.mainCategory;
  try {
    const subCategories = await Product.distinct('category.sub', { 'category.main': mainCategory });
    res.status(200).json(subCategories);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
}
```

Here is my DrawerNav Component :

```
const DrawerNav = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [subCategories, setSubCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategories = async (mainCategory, subCategory) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${mainCategory}/${subCategory}`);
        setCategories(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  const handleSubCategoryClick = async (mainCategory) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${mainCategory}`);
      setSubCategories(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Button
        variant="ghost"
        onClick={onOpen}
        _hover={{}}
      >
        <HamburgerIcon
          size="lg"
          w="32px"
          h="32px"
          m="10px"
          _hover={{}}
        />
      </Button>

      <Drawer
        isOpen={isOpen}
        placement="left"
        onClose={onClose}
      >
        <DrawerContent bg="gray.100">
          <DrawerCloseButton />
          <DrawerHeader fontSize="25px">Categories</DrawerHeader>

          <DrawerBody>
            <VStack
              divider={<StackDivider borderColor='gray.200' />}
              spacing={2}
              align='stretch'
            >
              <Box>
              <Accordion>
                    {categories.map((category) => (
                      <AccordionItem key={category.mainCategory}>
                        <h2>
                          <AccordionButton onClick={() => handleSubCategoryClick(category.mainCategory)}>
                            <Box
                              as="span"
                              flex="1"
                              textAlign="left"
                              fontWeight="bold"
                              fontSize="20px"
                            >
                              {category.mainCategory}
                            </Box>
                            <AccordionIcon />
                          </AccordionButton>
                        </h2>
                        <AccordionPanel pb={4}>
                          <Stack>
                            {subCategories.map((subCategory) => (
                              <Link key={subCategory} to={`/${category.mainCategory}/${subCategory}`}>{subCategory}</Link>
                            ))}
                          </Stack>
                        </AccordionPanel>
                      </AccordionItem>
                    ))}
               </Accordion>

              </Box>
            </VStack>
          </DrawerBody>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Here is Accordian,jsx, the component that is supposed to render products related to the sub categories defined in DrawerNav :

```
import { ChevronDownIcon, ChevronRightIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'
import { Grid, GridItem, Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuList, Button, Box, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, BreadcrumbLink} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Card from '../products/components/homePage/ProductItem'

const Accordian = () => {

  const {mainCategory} = useParams();
  const {subCategory} = useParams();

  const [products, setProducts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${mainCategory}/${subCategory}`);
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, [mainCategory, subCategory]);


  return (
    <Box>
      
        <Box sx={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"inline-flex" ,justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
        
        <Breadcrumb spacing='8px' ml={7} mt={9} separator={<ChevronRightIcon color='gray.500' />}>
    <BreadcrumbItem >
      <BreadcrumbLink fontSize="18px"  href='#'>{products.category.mainCategory}</BreadcrumbLink>
    </BreadcrumbItem>
  
    <BreadcrumbItem>
      <BreadcrumbLink fontSize="18px" href='#'>{products.category.subCategory}</BreadcrumbLink>
    </BreadcrumbItem>
  
  </Breadcrumb>
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton as={Button} rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />} marginRight="40px" marginTop="30px" fontSize="18px" bg="black" color="white">
            Sort by
        </MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
            <MenuItem>Recent</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Oldest to Newest</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Price: Low to High</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Price: High to Low</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>

        </Box>

        

    <Grid templateColumns="repeat(5, 1fr)" gap={6} templateRows="repeat(2,1fr)" pt={6}>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <GridItem key={product._id}>
          <Card 
            id={product._id}
            image={product.image}
            title={product.title}
            price={product.price}
            description={product.description}
            location={product.location}
            condition={product.condition}
            category={product.category}
            seller={product.seller}
          />
        </GridItem>
      ))}
    </Grid>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Accordian
```

The problem with this code is that there aren't any errors that occur on the front end or backend, but when I check my Drawer component, it's empty and there aren't any main or sub categories defined even though I submitted products that had defined main and sub categories.
Obviously, the categories are returned as undefined, but I'm also not sure how to set up my routes with this. So far for visiting a sub category page, this is the route I have on my front end in React :

```
<Route path="/:mainCategory/:subCateogry" element={<Accordian/>} />
```

Let me know if anyone's got tips.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCategories = async (mainCategory, subCategory) => { // defined 2 parameters
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${mainCategory}/${subCategory}`);
            setCategories(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        };
        fetchCategories(); // function called without arguments
      }, []);
```

what I thought might be the cause is in the code above function definition in DrawerNav it takes 2 parameters `mainCategory` and `subCategory` and it is called without specifying any arguments on it.

Maybe you can try to pass the value you got from the router to that `fetchCategories` function call.